# does cvxpy need starting conditions provided is zeros are not satisfying contraints?

Tags: python, cvxpy

I am trying to modify the [maxrect](https://github.com/planetlabs/maxrect) library to solve for maximum rectangles unconstrained by orientation.

looking at the code I see the constraints are:

```py
    """ :param coordinates:
        A list of of [x, y] pairs describing a closed, convex polygon.
    """

    coordinates = np.array(coordinates)
    x_range = np.max(coordinates, axis=0)[0]-np.min(coordinates, axis=0)[0]
    y_range = np.max(coordinates, axis=0)[1]-np.min(coordinates, axis=0)[1]

    scale = np.array([x_range, y_range])
    sc_coordinates = coordinates/scale

    poly = Polygon(sc_coordinates)
    inside_pt = (poly.representative_point().x,
                 poly.representative_point().y)

    A1, A2, B = pts_to_leq(sc_coordinates)

    bl = cvxpy.Variable(2)
    tr = cvxpy.Variable(2)
    br = cvxpy.Variable(2)
    tl = cvxpy.Variable(2)
    obj = cvxpy.Maximize(cvxpy.log(tr[0] - bl[0]) + cvxpy.log(tr[1] - bl[1]))
    constraints = [bl[0] == tl[0],
                   br[0] == tr[0],
                   tl[1] == tr[1],
                   bl[1] == br[1],
                   ]

    for i in range(len(B)):
        if inside_pt[0] * A1[i] + inside_pt[1] * A2[i] <= B[i]:
            constraints.append(bl[0] * A1[i] + bl[1] * A2[i] <= B[i])
            constraints.append(tr[0] * A1[i] + tr[1] * A2[i] <= B[i])
            constraints.append(br[0] * A1[i] + br[1] * A2[i] <= B[i])
            constraints.append(tl[0] * A1[i] + tl[1] * A2[i] <= B[i])

        else:
            constraints.append(bl[0] * A1[i] + bl[1] * A2[i] >= B[i])
            constraints.append(tr[0] * A1[i] + tr[1] * A2[i] >= B[i])
            constraints.append(br[0] * A1[i] + br[1] * A2[i] >= B[i])
            constraints.append(tl[0] * A1[i] + tl[1] * A2[i] >= B[i])
```

that is, they convert each point in the circumscribing polygon to the Ax + Ay = B and check if the corners of the rectangle are inside of it, and maximize the diagonals. additionally, there are 4 constraints that ensure that the angles of the corners are aligned with the reference frame.

I was thinking I could just remove those 4 constraints.

However, this allows the rectangle to exceed the bounds of the circumscribing polygon. That may mean that I'm not entirely correct about the purpose of the above constraints. It could also be that now those points are allowed to drift from their cardinal orientation within the reference frame, so I tried adding different constraints to maintain cardinality of the rectangle's points:

```py
    if aligned:
        constraints.append(bl[0] == tl[0])
        constraints.append(br[0] == tr[0])
        constraints.append(tl[1] == tr[1])
        constraints.append(bl[1] == br[1])
    else:
        constraints.append(bl[0] < br[0])
        constraints.append(bl[0] < tr[0])
        constraints.append(tl[0] < br[0])
        constraints.append(tl[0] < tr[0])
        constraints.append(bl[1] < tl[1])
        constraints.append(bl[1] < tr[1])
        constraints.append(br[1] < tl[1])
        constraints.append(br[1] < tr[1])
```

Could someone help me to see what I am missing?

## sample problem:

```py
square = Polygon([(0,0), (0,2), (2,2), (2,0)], [
    [(0.5,0.5), (0.5,1.2), (1,1.2), (1,0.5)],
    [(1.1,1.1), (1.1,1.5), (1.5,1.5), (1.5,1.1)]
])
line = LineString((square.exterior.coords[0], square.exterior.coords[1]))
max_hull = find_maximal_convex_hull(line, square)
print('max hull', max_hull.wkt, max_hull.area)

# this line calls my cvypy script
pa = get_maximal_rectangle(max_hull.exterior.coords)
max_rect = Polygon([(pa[0][0],pa[0][1]), (pa[0][0],pa[1][1]), (pa[1][0],pa[1][1]), (pa[1][0],pa[0][1])])
print('max rectangle', pa)

plt.axis(xmin=-0.125,xmax=2.125,ymin=-0.125,ymax=2.125)

plt.plot(*square.exterior.xy, color='g')
[plt.plot(*i.xy, color='y') for i in square.interiors]

plt.plot(*max_hull.exterior.xy, color='b')
[plt.plot(*i.xy, color='r') for i in max_hull.interiors]

plt.plot(*max_rect.exterior.xy, color='r')

plt.show()
```

in the above code I am given a complex shape and an edge. I must cut this down to a (roughly/nearly) largest convex shape, and the edge must intersect that shape. this work I've already done, it is assigned to the variable *max_hull*.

Now, I want the largest rectangle in the shape, regardless of orientation. In the image below, drawn from the code above, I show the outer square in green (the left edge is the required edge), its holes in yellow, the remaining convex shape, that is the outer polygon given to my cvypy in blue, -- it extends from the visible bottom line up to the top -- and the candidate rectangle returned from cvxpy in red.

the log output is:

```
<ipython-input-2-efd2419ff139>:272: ShapelyDeprecationWarning: Iteration over multi-part geometries is deprecated and will be removed in Shapely 2.0. Use the `geoms` property to access the constituent parts of a multi-part geometry.
  for base in split(S, ll):
455 unique polygons considered
max hull POLYGON ((0 0.95, 0 2, 2 2, 2 1.95, 0 0.95)) 1.0999999999999999
max rectangle (array([7.13062842e-09, 9.50000011e-01]), array([1.99999998, 1.99999999]))
```

in order to use the maxrect library with modern cvypy and python, change get_max_rectangle (in **init**.py) solve statement to `prob.solve()` and the return statement. after applying my code, this is the customized function I am using:

```py
import numpy as np
import cvxpy
from shapely.geometry import Polygon


def rect2poly(ll, ur):
    """
    Convert rectangle defined by lower left/upper right
    to a closed polygon representation.
    """
    x0, y0 = ll
    x1, y1 = ur

    return [
        [x0, y0],
        [x0, y1],
        [x1, y1],
        [x1, y0],
        [x0, y0]
    ]


def get_intersection(coords):
    """Given an input list of coordinates, find the intersection
    section of corner coordinates. Returns geojson of the
    interesection polygon.
    """
    ipoly = None
    for coord in coords:
        if ipoly is None:
            ipoly = Polygon(coord)
        else:
            tmp = Polygon(coord)
            ipoly = ipoly.intersection(tmp)

    # close the polygon loop by adding the first coordinate again
    first_x = ipoly.exterior.coords.xy[0][0]
    first_y = ipoly.exterior.coords.xy[1][0]
    ipoly.exterior.coords.xy[0].append(first_x)
    ipoly.exterior.coords.xy[1].append(first_y)

    inter_coords = zip(
        ipoly.exterior.coords.xy[0], ipoly.exterior.coords.xy[1])

    inter_gj = {"geometry":
                {"coordinates": [inter_coords],
                 "type": "Polygon"},
                "properties": {}, "type": "Feature"}

    return inter_gj, inter_coords


def two_pts_to_line(pt1, pt2):
    """
    Create a line from two points in form of
    a1(x) + a2(y) = b
    """
    pt1 = [float(p) for p in pt1]
    pt2 = [float(p) for p in pt2]
    try:
        slp = (pt2[1] - pt1[1]) / (pt2[0] - pt1[0])
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        slp = 1e5 * (pt2[1] - pt1[1])
    a1 = -slp
    a2 = 1.
    b = -slp * pt1[0] + pt1[1]

    return a1, a2, b


def pts_to_leq(coords):
    """
    Converts a set of points to form Ax = b, but since
    x is of length 2 this is like A1(x1) + A2(x2) = B.
    returns A1, A2, B
    """

    A1 = []
    A2 = []
    B = []
    for i in range(len(coords) - 1):
        pt1 = coords[i]
        pt2 = coords[i + 1]
        a1, a2, b = two_pts_to_line(pt1, pt2)
        A1.append(a1)
        A2.append(a2)
        B.append(b)
    return A1, A2, B


def get_maximal_rectangle(coordinates, aligned=False):
    """
    Find the largest, inscribed, axis-aligned rectangle.
    :param coordinates:
        A list of of [x, y] pairs describing a closed, convex polygon.
    """

    coordinates = np.array(coordinates)
    x_range = np.max(coordinates, axis=0)[0]-np.min(coordinates, axis=0)[0]
    y_range = np.max(coordinates, axis=0)[1]-np.min(coordinates, axis=0)[1]

    scale = np.array([x_range, y_range])
    sc_coordinates = coordinates/scale

    rep_point = Polygon(sc_coordinates).representative_point()
    inside_pt = (rep_point.x, rep_point.y)

    A1, A2, B = pts_to_leq(sc_coordinates)

    bl = cvxpy.Variable(2)
    tr = cvxpy.Variable(2)
    br = cvxpy.Variable(2)
    tl = cvxpy.Variable(2)
    obj = cvxpy.Maximize(cvxpy.log(tr[0] - bl[0]) + cvxpy.log(tr[1] - bl[1]))
    constraints = []
    
    if aligned:
        constraints.append(bl[0] == tl[0])
        constraints.append(br[0] == tr[0])
        constraints.append(tl[1] == tr[1])
        constraints.append(bl[1] == br[1])
    else:
        constraints.append(bl[0] < br[0])
        constraints.append(bl[0] < tr[0])
        constraints.append(tl[0] < br[0])
        constraints.append(tl[0] < tr[0])
        constraints.append(bl[1] < tl[1])
        constraints.append(bl[1] < tr[1])
        constraints.append(br[1] < tl[1])
        constraints.append(br[1] < tr[1])
        
    for i in range(len(B)):
        if inside_pt[0] * A1[i] + inside_pt[1] * A2[i] <= B[i]:
            constraints.append(bl[0] * A1[i] + bl[1] * A2[i] <= B[i])
            constraints.append(tr[0] * A1[i] + tr[1] * A2[i] <= B[i])
            constraints.append(br[0] * A1[i] + br[1] * A2[i] <= B[i])
            constraints.append(tl[0] * A1[i] + tl[1] * A2[i] <= B[i])
        else:
            constraints.append(bl[0] * A1[i] + bl[1] * A2[i] >= B[i])
            constraints.append(tr[0] * A1[i] + tr[1] * A2[i] >= B[i])
            constraints.append(br[0] * A1[i] + br[1] * A2[i] >= B[i])
            constraints.append(tl[0] * A1[i] + tl[1] * A2[i] >= B[i])

    prob = cvxpy.Problem(obj, constraints)
    #prob.solve(solver=cvxpy.CVXOPT, verbose=False, max_iters=1000, reltol=1e-9)
    #prob.solve(solver=cvxpy.SCS, verbose=True, use_indirect=False, max_iters=int(1e5))
    prob.solve()

    bottom_left = np.array(bl.value).T * scale
    top_right = np.array(tr.value).T * scale
    
    #return list(bottom_left[0]), list(top_right[0])
    return bottom_left, top_right
```

No other function in the above was modified.

[image: example failing rectangle in red]

Answer (score 0):

The problem of finding an area-maximizing unconstrained rectangle contained in a polygon is non-convex, so you simply have no chance to express it using cvxpy.

The constraints you removed mean you have an axis-aligned rectangle, without them you just have an arbitrary 4-gon contained in the big polygon for which you are maximizing the product of two sides - not something intuitive or what you wanted.

See for instance https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/powo.html#maximum-volume-cuboid

Comment: I'm not looking for the the general solution for a polygon, but for the solution for a convex polygon, which has naive solutions in O(n^4) and more sophisticated ones in much lower bounds. But the question in this case is about why the remaining constraints and objective are leading to a solution outside of the bounds of the these same constraints in CVXpy , I can take it from there (I realize it may not in fact be optimal).

Comment: Even if the polygon is convex the problem is still non-convex and not doable in cvxpy. Sorry. As for the rest you would have to post a fully reproducible example.

Comment: even if the solution won't be very good it should still return a candidate that fits the rmaining bounds. Your guidance about the overall problem is appreciated but please let us now focus on the question -- here's a sample: outer polygon: POLYGON ((0 0.95, 0 2, 2 2, 2 1.95, 0 0.95)) I'll post an image that shows the result array([7.13062842e-09, 9.50000011e-01]), array([1.99999998, 1.99999999]) is larger than it